# How to add service entry for azure in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, azure, laravel-socialite

I want to add microsoft azure as an authentication method. I have followed laravel's and socialites documentation to add other methods than provided by laravel.

I have followed all the steps but I keep getting the error:

```
"SocialiteProviders \ Manager \ Exception \ MissingConfigException
There is no services entry for azure"
```

app.php:

```
'providers' => [
    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    // Some more providers

    \SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::class,

],

'aliases' => [
    'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,

],
```

EventServiceProvider.php:

```
    protected $listen = [
    Registered::class => [
        SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
    ],
    \SocialiteProviders\Manager\SocialiteWasCalled::class => [
        'SocialiteProviders\\Azure\\AzureExtendSocialite@handle',
    ],

];
```

services.php:

```
'azure' => [
    'client_id' => 'MY_ID',
    'client_secret' => 'MY_SECRET',
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/login/azure/callback',
],
```

Login Controller:

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialite::with('azure')->redirect();
}

/**
 * Obtain the user information from GitHub.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    $user = Socialite::with('azure')->user();

    // $user->token;
}
```

I can not find anything about this problem on the internet.
It seems like it's not reading the "azure" entry in services.php, but I have no idea how to fix it.

EDIT: Yes I have installed everything with composer.

Comment: try `composer dumpautoload` ?

Comment: @Saphnesh Naik already done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far I can see, is this an issue with your config caching. Here for you have to run `php artisan config:clear`, this will remove the caching of the config.